# How can I cast an AbstractControl to a FormControl in a template?

Tags: angular

I have a FormGroup that I'm passing from a parent component to a child, and then within that FormGroup there's a control that I'm passing from the first child to a second child. However I then want to use the control in a button so that I can alter the state of the formgroup using it.

However when I do form.get('controlName'), it returns an AbstractControl, and when I try to pass the AbstractControl to the `[formControl]` directive of the button I get an error saying that `Type AbstractControl is not assignable to abstract control`.

Usually I'd just cast the control to a FormControl in my component but this won't work as I'm using the control directly in the template.

The form

```
this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
      cost: this._formBuilder.control(''),
      width: this._formBuilder.control('')
    })
```

First child template

```
<app-form-subsection-cost [subsectionFormControl]="form.get('cost')"></app-form-subsection-cost>
```

Second child

```
export class FormSubsectionCostComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() subsectionFormControl: AbstractControl;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Second child template

```
<button [formControl]="subsectionFormControl as FormControl" value="Yes">Yes</button> //Error on formControl directive
```

I can't do this:

```
<app-form-subsection-cost [subsectionFormControl]="form.get('cost')"
[subsectionFormControl]="form.get('cost') as FormControl"></app-form-subsection-cost>
```

Answer (score 5):

What I do is define a method in my component to return the FormControl with a given name.

```
  fc(name) { return this.form.get(name) as FormControl; }
```

Then use it in the template:

```
  [formControl]="fc('subsectionFormControl')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a method like Thor suggested, but unfortunately the best supported out-of-the-box solution I have found is to use the [$any() cast function](https://angular.io/guide/template-expression-operators#any-type-cast-function).  This is less safe, but you don't have to add a cast function to every affected component.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth: define setter / getter, and allow superclass on setter:

```
@Input() 
set control(control: AbstractControl) {
    this._control = control as FormControl;
}
get control(): FormControl {
    return this._control;
}
```

If there's a chance the cast in the setter will backfire, do a typeof + throw Error beforehand to fail-fast.